# How to save byte array into an binary file in java

Tags: java

How to save byte array into an binary file in java. I have tries using file writer,bufferedOutputstream but with no results. The data gets saved in the binary file, when the file is opened with notepad, it looks like binary file has been created but when opened with wordpad the actual data appears.

Comment: Please send your code. And would you please add some punctuation signs? You know, dots, comas etc... These little signs could help to understand what do you mean.

Comment: `The data gets saved in the binary file, when the file is opened with notepad, it looks like binary file has been created but when opened with wordpad the actual data appears.` All files are binary, you know? Its just how you interpret those bytes.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to illustrate what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save byte array in this way:

```
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
  String strContent = "Content";

  /*
   * To write byte array to a file, use
   * void write(byte[] bArray) method of Java FileOutputStream class.
   *
   * This method writes given byte array to a file.
   */

   fos.write(strContent.getBytes());

  /*
   * Close FileOutputStream using,
   * void close() method of Java FileOutputStream class.
   *
   */

   fos.close();
```

It will create a file with your byte array